# gstreamer pipeline saves my camera stream to a file, but I need a pipeline to stream it live to my monitor

Tags: gstreamer

ok, this works

This gstreamer pipeline works well to save my camera video stream to a file on my raspberry pi.

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,format=UYVY' ! v4l2h264enc ! 'video/x-h264,level=(string)4' ! filesink location = test_video6.h264

but what is the correct pipeline to display a live video stream from my camera in order to watch it  in real time on my monitor, instead of just saving it to a file to view it later with VLC.

For example, I have tried adding
! videoconvert ! autovideosink
to the above pipeline, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,format=UYVY' ! v4l2h264enc ! 'video/x-h264,level=(string)4' ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

If this doesn't work you can use the general example of a video pipeline from [here](https://gist.github.com/velovix/8cbb9bb7fe86a08fb5aa7909b2950259) and use:

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

from there you can add the settings you want.

EDIT: Another implementation is creating a tee of your file and send it to play through a queue in this case you do:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,format=UYVY' ! v4l2h264enc ! 'video/x-h264,level=(string)4'! tee name="source"! queue ! filesink location = test_video6.h264 source. ! queue !  decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Comment: v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
No already tried these and getAdditional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)

Comment: This works. It opens with VLC. Now i'll fine tune it      gst-launch-1.0 -vc udpsrc -vvv -e port=5600 close-socket=false multicast-iface=false auto-multicast=true ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink

Comment: This is odd.  Now this works.       gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,format=UYVY' ! v4l2h264enc ! 'video/x-h264,level=(string)4' ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Comment: I think it is about missing a decodebin. You add raw data to pipeline and GStreamer can't send the data in a playable format at the sink you ask. That's why you get the error: "streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)" .

Comment: I think i found the solution you need, check edited answer